# How to make a .png file created in script readable so that it can be accessed later?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I need to be able to save and load images which can be opened outside of the application I am creating, but the images I am creating cannot be used the next time I open the project.

My current method involves rendering a portion of the visible screen to a Texture2D and then encoding that to a .png file through the EncodeToPNG() function. The problem is, the image files created in this way are not readable and I don't know if it's possible to make them readable in script. It would be an incredible help to me if it was possible to make them read-write enabled in script as the images were created.

Current code (modified slightly to make it more readable):

```
    //set the render texture to a render texture created previously
    pictureCam.targetTexture = rendering;

    //create a new texture to hold the desired graphic
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(CardWidth, CardHeight, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

    //render to the render texture
    pictureCam.Render();
    RenderTexture.active = pictureCam.targetTexture;

    //read pixels from the render texture to the new texture2D
    texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(imageWidth, imageHeight, CardWidth, CardHeight), 0, 0);

    //create a new .png image from the texture2D (saved later) and reset the camera's target texture
    byte[] bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
    pictureCam.targetTexture = null;
```

All new Texture2D files created in script are automatically read-write enabled, so I expected other files created in script to be read-write enabled but apparently something about my code is preventing this for other image types created in script.

Comment: The problem is, the image files created in this way are not readable..."  Q: What do you mean?  You get a valid .png file, don't you?  Can you open it MSPaint?  In what way is it "not readable"?

Comment: `cannot be used the next time I open the project.` Where/How are you traing to access them? How do you save them?

Comment: They appear and are usable in the inspector but Unity does not mark them as Read-write enabled so I cannot edit them in scripts. The file is valid and I can open it in other things, but I cannot do anything with it in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This function fixed my problem, I called it after the .png file was saved and each time it was loaded:

```
{
    //get the filename of a texture T
    string filename = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(T);

    //get the texture importer of the texture and set isReadable to true unless no texture is found at the filename
    TextureImporter importer = (TextureImporter)AssetImporter.GetAtPath(filename);
    if (importer != null)
        importer.isReadable = true;
    else
        Debug.Log("No Importer");
}`
```